# ASP.Net Core ODataController Attribute Routing throws 500 error during insert

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to implement Create and update logic on my `ODataController` on ASP.Net core 5.0 using `8.0.0-beta`. My controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("users/{key}/{operation}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateUser([FromODataUri] string key, [FromODataUri] string operation, [FromBody] Delta<User> userPatch)
{
    IActionResult result = BadRequest($"Key:{key} / Operation:{operation.ToLower()}");
    if (operation.ToLower() == "update")
    {
        result = await Patch(key, userPatch);
        return result;
    }
    else if (operation.ToLower() == "create")
    {
        var newUser = new User();
        userPatch.Patch(newUser);
        var entity = await AddNewEntity(newUser, key);
        result = Created(entity);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The `update` is working fine, I am able to verify using the REST client(`http://localhost:5000/users/MY-USER-6/update`)

However when I call `create` method using the REST client (`http://localhost:5000/users/MY-USER-6/create`) I see that the ***method works*** and data is inserted in the database and function exits without an issue, however the result I get on the REST client the response says `Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error` with the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The request must have an associated EDM model. Consider using the extension method HttpConfiguration.MapODataServiceRoute to register a route that parses the OData URI and attaches the model information.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Results.ResultHelpers.GenerateODataLink(HttpRequest request, Object entity, Boolean isEntityId)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Results.CreatedODataResult`1.GenerateLocationHeader(HttpRequest request)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Results.CreatedODataResult`1.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

BTW if I change `result = Created(entity);` to `result = Ok(entity);` its working fine!

As per some blogs and channel9 videos I am trying to add `endpoints.EnableDependencyInjection();` but looks like this is no longer available or may be valid in the `8.0.0-beta`.

What am I missing in this?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `ODataController` you need to name your method `Post` if it should be added into your url paths as a OData endpoint.

Make sure the type returned from `UpdateUser` is added to your EDM model and linked to your controller

```
static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<User>("Users");
    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

then add controller like

```
services
   .AddControllers()
   .AddOData(opt => opt
       .AddRouteComponents("v1", GetEdmModel())
       .Filter().Select().Expand().OrderBy());
```

Users endpoints will be available at `/v1/Users` - it is important the name of your controller is `UsersController` and your method `UpdateUser` is renamed to `Post`.

The reason your endpoint is currently reachable is because you have added an `[Route("users/{key}/{operation}")]` attribute. Because of this it will be available but not as a OData endpoint.

If you look at the source code of `ODataController` is overwrites `Created` and `Updated`
https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/blob/dd8b5cd73bd8cfa1756241171aa359452f60ae80/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/Routing/Controllers/ODataController.cs

Looking at the implementation of `Created` it access the EDM model when it creates the response at

```
Uri location = GenerateLocationHeader(request);
```

https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/blob/dd8b5cd73bd8cfa1756241171aa359452f60ae80/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/Results/CreatedODataResult.cs#L52

Since the endpoint you target (method `UpdateUser`), isn't a OData endpoint with a linked EDM model it fails.

Looking at the implemenation of `Updated` it doesn't use the EDM model - this is why you succeed having this as return type even though your endpoint isn't a OData endpoint.

https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/blob/dd8b5cd73bd8cfa1756241171aa359452f60ae80/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/Results/UpdatedODataResult.cs#L40

If you don't use the OData middleware you can change your controller to inherit from `ControllerBase`. Then the endpoint will, as now, be accessible at `[Route("users/{key}/{operation}")]` and `Created` will work is normal.

#### Naming issue example

Try making an EDM model and controllers like this

```
static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<Droid>("Droids");
    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}

...

services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddOData(opt => opt
        .AddRouteComponents("v1", GetEdmModel())
        .Filter().Select().Expand().OrderBy());

...

app.MapControllers();
```

Then create controller

```
public class DroidsController : ODataController
{
    [EnableQuery]
    public IActionResult WrongNamePost([FromBody]Droid droid)
    {
        return Created(droid);
    }
}
```

Your endpoints should be available at `/v1/Droids` but it isn't.

Rename your method to

```
    [EnableQuery]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Droid droid)
    {
        return Created(droid);
    }
```

Now it is available as a OData endpoint at `/v1/Droids`.

#### Validate your endpoints

You can validate your endpoints by adding Swagger.

In `Program.cs`

```
services
   .AddSwaggerGen(c =>
   {
       c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new() { Title = "OdataTurorial", Version = "v1" });
   });
...

app.UseSwagger();
```

Then you can see if endpoints are added correctly at `http://localhost:YOUR_PORT/swagger/v1/swagger.json`.